# ASP.NET Core URL rewriting with query parameters

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a LitElement based SPA with an ASP.NET Core backend which hosts the static files and a REST API for loading data into the SPA.

The user starts with /index.html and the client-side router brings him to, f.e.,
/data-analysis or /dashboard.

When the user now presses the browser refresh button she gets 404 which is to be expected since the server does not know any of these subpaths.

I read elsewhere that I have to take care of this on the server side, so I came up with this middleware in my Startup.cs Configure method:

```
  app.Use(async (c, next) =>
  {              
      //Identify subpaths...

      c.Request.Path = "/index.html";                  

      await next();
  });
```

For all subpaths it brings the user back to index.html which is nice. Better yet would be to let the client side know which subpath to restore. For this I added the following lines to the code above:

```
  var url = c.Request.Path.Value;
  c.Request.QueryString = c.Request.QueryString.Add("page", $"{url.Substring(1)}");
```

I expected the client to see a window.location of, f.e.

.../index.html?page=data-analysis

but the query string never arrives, window.location.search is always empty on the client side.

Is this possible at all or am I misunderstanding something here?

Nicolas

Comment: Have you tried [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: Thanks for link. While reading this article I noticed that what I actually should do is redirecting and not rewriting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studying Microsofts documentation about the URL rewriting middleware led me to the conclusion that I should redirect and not rewrite! The following code produces the desired result. Note that the 'return' statement is critical, because no further middleware should be called!

```
app.Use(async (c, next) =>
{              
  var url = c.Request.Path.Value; 

  //Identify subpaths...

  if(... should redirect ...)
  {
      c.Response.Redirect($"/index.html?page={url.Substring(1)}");                
      return;
  }

  await next();
});
```